# Listening to php echo with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I send some data to the server using ajax and I receive 2 variables, success and error, depending on if the mail was sent or not. How do I listen to them with ajax and how do I alert them and is the php code correct?

php code:

```
if ($send){
    echo json_encode($success);
} else { echo json_encode($error);
    }
```

Comment: doesnt anyone has a solution that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a such way

```
$result["error"] = false;
if($send) {
    $result["data"] = $success
    echo json_encode($result);
} else {
    $result["error"] = true;
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: and for the $.ajax part? how would it look?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that your `$send` variable is the return value from the `mail()` function, something similar to this:

```
$headers = 'From: from@from.com';
$send = mail('test@test.com', 'Subject', 'Message', $headers);

echo json_encode(array( 'success' => ($send ? 1 : 0)));
```

You can call this via AJAX using jQuery in this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/script.php',
    success: function( json ) {
        var obj = JSON.parse( json );
        if(obj['success'] == 1) {
            alert('Success!');
        } else {
            alert('Fail!');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: you are right, the $send is defined like this: $send = @mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, "From: ".$mailFrom1);                           However when I try your solution I get the following error:  200 SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data.       The email is sent nevertheless, but from 2 senders.

Comment: Try navigating to the page directly in your browser that you are calling via AJAX.  What you should see as output is something along the lines of: `{"success":1}` (it will also resend the email)

Comment: You really lost me here...The page that I am calling is a simple script to send emails that is also blocked with     event.preventDefault(); I just need to get the false or true variable so I can make some changes using jquery.

Comment: I see what you are saying now, but the post does not redirect as you have supposed as it is blocked from jquery.

Comment: What I meant was, navigate to the URL you specified in the `url` property of the AJAX call (above it would be `http://www.server.com/path/to/script.php`) and tell me what it outputs.  It should be something like: `{"success":1}`